# Sorting and WHERE with CUID customer Unique ID's

Tags: sorting, prisma

Ran into an odd issue i never saw coming, I need to create a prisma query to grab a user record after one I have the CUID for.  Sorting works just fine but using greater than does not as per the non numeric values of CUID.  I could do some work arounds with mutiple queries but I have to assume there is some way of doing this easily!

basic query as such

```
async function getProps({ params }) {
  const users= await prisma.user.findMany({
    select: {
      id:true,
      name: true,
      email: true,
    },
    where : { id: { gt: lastId }, },
    orderBy: { id: "asc" },
  });
  return data;
}
```

lastId being a user.id in CUID format.